# How to get the most money out of potentially totalled car?

Tags: mazda, repair, replace, mazda-6

I crashed my car :( Accidentally rearended a pickup :(
It's not drivable because the radiator fell out, but I was told by the guy who towed it that the frame wasn't damaged.
I don't know what to do with it now. I'd really like to avoid towing it all over the place trying to get the best quote, but I'm not sure I could get a decent quote from just the pictures:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0WYKxtipNPVT0g4dEtMV2tJNnM

Also, it's 2008 and has 60,000 miles and probably only costs 9000 or so, so if I'm not able to fix it for a decent price, I'd have to somehow get rid of it and buy a new one. Do you guys know what would be the best way to get rid of it to make as much money back as possible? I just put new tires on it too the day before :(

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell us from which country you are from. Maybe the state also makes a difference.

Comment: I'm in Florida. (Sorry, forgot to log in before posting the question)

Comment: Based on the tags I was going to guess California. The other thing to consider is how much different any quote is going to be. If you shop it around and spend $500 on towing to make an extra $250... For your own sanity, get a reputable shop to give you a quote, just don't use a dealer unless you want to pay the max. Sorry you have to go through this. I've done it one and it's a pain no matter how you slice it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the space you could part out the vehicle or sell whole as is. With that amount of damage I can see the repair value is high. If you need it gone quick you will get quick price. IMO

Engine 200-400
Transmission 150-300
Doors 70-100
Deck lid 50
Fenders 50

Price can change but idea... These are typical junk yard prices. If you go this route then drain ALL FLUIDS yourself! Especially gasoline.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a lot... unless you're missing some zeros here and there... Why do I have to drain the fluids myself?

Comment: If you dont then other people won't care and you will have this and that all over the place. Those prices are tentative... You can charge what you like.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying... Others won't care about what? And I was asking what you meant by "high" repair value, not prices per part, as I don't plan on selling them individually